# deleting row from datagridview

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to delete row from datagridview when user clicks the delete button.The datagridview bounded to datatable _dt so i remove the row from _dt and try to rebind the modified _dt to datagridview but instead of deleting the row gets added to the last row of the datagridview what am I doing wrong here

```
    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1 != null && dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
        {
            string key = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();
            DataColumn[] keyColumns = new DataColumn[1];
            keyColumns[0] = _dt.Columns["ID"];
            _dt.PrimaryKey = keyColumns;
            rowToDelete = _dt.Rows.Find(key);
            _dt.Rows.Remove(rowToDelete);
            _dt.AcceptChanges();
            SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(_sqlDa);
            _sqlDa.Fill(_dt);
            _sqlDa.Update(_dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = _dt;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are not needed to call Fill Method there. or If you want than use after Update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for Fill before update and also delete this row

```
    _dt.AcceptChanges();
```

because this will remove the row from memory and when you call update
only the remaining rows are updated, it will not delete the row from database.

Answer (score 0):

No need to call Fill Before Update, because Fill will get data again from db and your changes will be lost. So This will work for you.

```
SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(_sqlDa);
//_sqlDa.Fill(_dt);
_sqlDa.Update(_dt);
```